# Microsoft Teams asks for login information at every startup

Tags: login, auto-login, microsoft-teams

I recently installed Microsoft Teams 1.4.00.26453 (64-bit) on my Ubuntu 21.10 laptop.

My problem is that Teams keeps asking for the login information of my organization every time it starts. I have double checked that both my web browser and the website have my login information and after entering it everything works fine, it's just that it seems to forget it when I turn off the computer.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently this has to do with the cookies and site data of the website you are trying to log into.

Clear the cookies and site data of the website where you input your login information and then login using Teams normally.