# Teams - redirects me to a corporate login

Tags: microsoft-teams

I am on ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS - this is a private laptop.
The OS was installed by me with Ubuntu 18 and updated to 20.04.

Few years ago I used to log in via Teams (.deb package installed from the Microsoft website) to my previous employer with my private laptop.

Now when I start Teams, the normal Microsoft Teams logins appears.
If I put there the email address of my university (a new one), it redirects me to a different screen (also in the Teams app), however this teams has the background and logo of my old employer. And here it doesn't accept my university login of course.

However I can't find a way to login normally... whatever I do it redirects me to the old organization Teams.

Uninstall and reinstall Teams didn't help. The same issue.

Anybody knows how to login normally on Teams on Ubuntu and/or how to remove the old organization data stored somewhere?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1375548/microsoft-teams-asks-for-login-information-at-every-startup  Regarding the remove: did you use PURGE? If not purge and install

Comment: I used only `sudo apt remove teams`

Comment: I just tried `sudo apt purge teams` and resintalled it. Still the same problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution found. The following worked:
-uninstall
-removed the Microsoft and Microsoft Teams folders from `~/.config/Microsoft/Microsoft Teams/`
-reinstalled

Comment: Don't forget to accept your solution.